# Deploying Azure apps to Windows Servers

Tags: asp.net, deployment, azure

We're preparing to create a web-centred platform for schools, and we were planning to host it in Azure. However, public schools have certain limitations that prevent them from openly accessing the internet, which means that an Azure based system wouldn't work there.

Is it possible to deploy the same project to local servers, and the Azure cloud without fragmenting our codebase?

Comment: So many good answers to pick from! StackOverflow at its best :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what aspects of Azure you are using within your solution. If you have a manilla ASP.NET app, and not using Azure dependencies such as AppFabric or any of the Azure SDK such as blob storage, then you will be able to deploy to a standard instance of IIS.

If you are using Azure dependencies, I would try your best to seperate these within your codebase, as per practice to abstract any dependencies. You would then be able to switch out based on a config change to not use them, and revert to a local or stubbed alternative when deploying to Windows. This would be the same for when running CI/builds too.

Comment: This is what I would say. If Azure is heavily integrated with your app, for example Table Storage was your primary storage mechanism rather than SQL Azure it could be difficult. But if you just have it sprinkled in a few spots shouldn't be hard to abstract out.

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on what your application is doing.  The Azure deployment project (the .ccproj project) and related .cspkg package wouldn't be applicable to a Windows Server deployment.

If you're application uses Windows Azure specific features (for example, table storage), then you're going to have to handle that on-premises somehow.  If you're looking to have one code-base that runs both on-premises and on Windows Azure, one option could be to go with a dependency injection approach that could inject the correct implementation of a feature based on the target deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this real world scenario with a client. They have customers who want to continue using their product installed on their own servers. At the same time they have newer customers who would like to rent their application as a service and use a pay-as-you-go model.

Does this mean two code bases? No but it means you have to be willing to go the extra miles in regards to development abstractions and inversion of control.

Generally speaking I would go about this problem like so:

- Design for Windows Azure, meaning use the API for the Windows Azure SDK.
- Add an abstraction layer between the real Windows Azure SDK and your code.
- Provide an alternate implementation for the Windows Azure dependencies for on premise installations.

Also...

- Use code that is already out there like [Azure Contrib](http://azurecontrib.codeplex.com/). This OSS project contains the start of such an abstraction layer along with other hopefully helpful Windows Azure code.

And don't forget to have fun! ;~)